# How to form equilateral triangles using R?

Tags: r

I wanted to draw 2 equilateral triangles. One upside down and the other upside up. 
Here is my code:

```
 ord<-c(1,3,5)
 ord1<-c(2,4,6) 

 x1<-x[ord]
 y1<-y[ord]
 x2<-x[ord1]
 y2<-y[ord1]

 lines(x1,y1,col="blue")
 lines(x2,y2,col="blue")
```

However, I can't get the figure to make complete triangle. I only get 2 sides of each triangle. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where does the x and y variables come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lines will draw from the first coord to the second, second to third, etc. If you want it to come back to the first point, just duplicate it at the end:

```
ord <- c(1,3,5,1)
ord1 <- c(2,4,6,2)
```

to get it come back to the first point.

Comment: Thank you. It connects now!

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that the third point is halfway between the first and the second, and the angle is pi/3, you can do this for example:

```
angle=pi/3
x <- c(0,0.5,0.5*cos(angle),0)
y <- c(0,0,sin(angle),0)
y1 <- c(0,0,-sin(angle),0)

plot(-1:1,-1:1,type='n')
polygon(x=x,y=y,col='red')      ## you can replace polygon by lines here 
polygon(x=x,y=y1,col='green')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank You for your example. It helped me understand!